# Ruby Hash whose key is a function of the object?

Tags: ruby, hash

For instance,

```
s1 = Student.new(1, "Bob", "Podunk High")
hash[1] = s1
puts hash[1].name    #produces "Bob"
s1.id = 15
puts hash[15].name   #produces "Bob"
puts hash[1].name    #fails
```

This is not exactly Hash-like behavior and insertions with the wrong key still needs to be defined.

While I can certainly roll my own container that behaves this way but it will be hard to make it fast, ie not search through the whole container every time [] is called. Just wondering if someone smarter has already made something I can steal.

EDIT: Some good ideas below helped me focus my requirements:

1. avoid the O(n) lookup time
2. allow multiple containers to the same object (association not composition)
3. have different data types (eg. that might use `name` instead of `id`) without too much reimplementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement it yourself.

Look at the draft solution:

```
class Campus
  attr_reader :students
  def initialize
    @students = []
  end

  def [](ind)
    students.detect{|s| s.id == ind}
  end

  def <<(st)
    raise "Yarrr, not a student"   if st.class != Student
    raise "We already have got one with id #{st.id}" if self[st.id]
    students << st
  end
end

class Student
  attr_accessor :id, :name, :prop
  def initialize(id, name, prop)
    @id, @name, @prop = id, name, prop
  end
end

campus = Campus.new
st1 = Student.new(1, "Pedro", "Math")
st2 = Student.new(2, "Maria", "Opera")
campus << st1
campus << st2
campus[1]
#=> Student...id:1,name:pedro...
campus[2].name
#=> Maria
campus[2].id = 10
campus[2]
#=> error
campus[10].name
#=> Maria
```

Or you can play around Array class (or Hash, if you really need it):

```
class StrangeArray < Array
  def [](ind)
    self.detect{|v| v.id == ind} || raise "nothing found" # if you really need to raise an error
  end

  def <<(st)
    raise "Looks like a duplicate" if self[st.id]
    self.push(st)
  end
end

campus = StrangeArray.new
campus << Student.new(15, 'Michael', 'Music')
campus << Student.new(40, 'Lisa', 'Medicine')
campus[1]
#=> error 'not found'
campus[15].prop
#=> Music
campus[15].id = 20
campus[20].prop
#=> Music
```

etc

And after @tadman's correct comment you can use reference to your `hash` right into your Student class:

```
class Student
  attr_accessor :name, :prop
  attr_reader :id, :campus
  def initialize(id, name, prop, camp=nil)
    @id, @name, @prop = id, name, prop
    self.campus = camp if camp
  end

  def id=(new_id)
    if campus
      rase "this id is already taken in campus" if campus[new_id]
      campus.delete id
      campus[new_id] = self
    end
    @id = new_id
  end

  def campus=(camp)
    rase "this id is already taken in campus" if camp[id]
    @campus = camp
    camp[@id] = self
  end
end

campus = {}
st1 = Student.new(1, "John", "Math")
st2 = Student.new(2, "Lisa", "Math", campus)
# so now in campus is only Lisa
st1.campus = campus
# we've just pushed John in campus
campus[1].name
#=> John
campus[1].id = 10
campus[10].name
#=> John
```

Comment: I'm not sure spinning through all the values with `detect` when looking for a match is an especially savvy way to go about solving this problem.

Comment: oh, thats why we need hash here. got it. But the problem is that hee need it dynamically change when exact object is changed etc. So it is more complicated because each `Stdent` should know about his campus to tell him about `id is changed`. so `detect` is just the simplest solution, but not the best

Comment: That's a good point, but hopefully `id` is an immutable database property. I've added an answer that's optimized for that solution.

Comment: Why do you think it is immutable and why do you think it is about database? Right in the question author changing id :)

Comment: You are right: it's not mutable and it's not in the database. Since this is NOT a database table, there are multiple hashes linking to Student, which makes things hairy very fast. Not to mention that there are many different data objects I want to support, most of them far more complex than Student, and I have no intention of editing all of them. And have them break when someone uses them with normal hashes. All in all, a pain in the @ss. :(

Comment: In any case I already have a "better" version of floor's answer that allows you to pass a block at container creation time instead of hardcoding to `{|s| s.id == ind}` so I can use it for non-Students (I'm going to accept your answer, so you can update for posterity if you want). I just wanted to see if there is a better way, didn't get my hopes too high up.

Answer (score 1):

The container must be notified when your key has been changed, otherwise you must search the key on the fly in `lg(n)`.

If you rarely change key and lookup a lot, just rebuild the hash:

```
def build_hash_on_attribute(objects, attribute)
  Hash[objects.collect { |e| [e.send(method), e] }]
end

s1 = OpenStruct.new id: 1, name: 's1'

h = build_hash_on_attribute([s1], :id)
h[1].name # => 's1'

h[1].id = 15
# rebuild the whole index after any key attribute has been changed
h = build_hash_on_attribute(h.values, :id)
h[1] # => nil
h[15].name # => 's1'
```

---

**Update 02/12**: Add a solution using observer pattern

Or you do need such automatically index building, you can use observer pattern like below or decorator pattern. But you need to use the wrapped objects in decorator pattern.

gist: https://gist.github.com/1807324

```
module AttrChangeEmitter
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend ClassMethods
    base.send :include, InstanceMethods
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def attr_change_emitter(*attrs)
      attrs.each do |attr|
        class_eval do
          alias_method "#{attr}_without_emitter=", "#{attr}="
          define_method "#{attr}_with_emitter=" do |v|
            previous_value = send("#{attr}")
            send "#{attr}_without_emitter=", v
            attr_change_listeners_on(attr).each do |listener|
              listener.call self, previous_value, v
            end
          end
          alias_method "#{attr}=", "#{attr}_with_emitter="
        end
      end
    end
  end

  module InstanceMethods
    def attr_change_listeners_on(attr)
      @attr_change_listeners_on ||= {}
      @attr_change_listeners_on[attr.to_sym] ||= []
    end

    def add_attr_change_listener_on(attr, block)
      listeners = attr_change_listeners_on(attr)
      listeners << block unless listeners.include?(block)
    end

    def remove_attr_change_listener_on(attr, block)
      attr_change_listeners_on(attr).delete block
    end
  end
end

class AttrChangeAwareHash
  include Enumerable

  def initialize(attr = :id)
    @attr = attr.to_sym
    @hash = {}
  end

  def each(&block)
    @hash.values.each(&block)
  end

  def on_entity_attr_change(e, previous_value, new_value)
    if @hash[previous_value].equal? e
      @hash.delete(previous_value)
      # remove the original one in slot new_value
      delete_by_key(new_value)
      @hash[new_value] = e
    end
  end

  def add(v)
    delete(v)
    v.add_attr_change_listener_on(@attr, self.method(:on_entity_attr_change))
    k = v.send(@attr)
    @hash[k] = v
  end

  alias_method :<<, :add

  def delete(v)
    k = v.send(@attr)
    delete_by_key(k) if @hash[k].equal?(v)
  end

  def delete_by_key(k)
    v = @hash.delete(k)
    v.remove_attr_change_listener_on(@attr, self.method(:on_entity_attr_change)) if v
    v
  end

  def [](k)
    @hash[k]
  end
end

class Student
  include AttrChangeEmitter
  attr_accessor :id, :name
  attr_change_emitter :id, :name

  def initialize(id, name)
    self.id = id
    self.name = name
  end
end

indexByIDA = AttrChangeAwareHash.new(:id)
indexByIDB = AttrChangeAwareHash.new(:id)
indexByName = AttrChangeAwareHash.new(:name)

s1 = Student.new(1, 'John')
s2 = Student.new(2, 'Bill')
s3 = Student.new(3, 'Kate')

indexByIDA << s1
indexByIDA << s3

indexByIDB << s1
indexByIDB << s2

indexByName << s1
indexByName << s2
indexByName << s3

puts indexByIDA[1].name # => John
puts indexByIDB[2].name # => Bill
puts indexByName['John'].id # => 1

s2.id = 15
s2.name = 'Batman'

p indexByIDB[2] # => nil
puts indexByIDB[15].name # => Batman

indexByName.each do |v|
  v.name = v.name.downcase
end

p indexByName['John'] # => nil
puts indexByName['john'].id # => 1

p indexByName.collect { |v| [v.id, v.name] }
# => [[1, "john"], [3, "kate"], [15, "batman"]]

indexByName.delete_by_key 'john'
indexByName.delete(s2)

s2.id = 1 # set batman id to 1 to overwrite john
p indexByIDB.collect { |v| [v.id, v.name] }
# => [[1, "batman"]]

p indexByName.collect { |v| [v.id, v.name] }
# => [[3, "kate"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

While the Hash object might not behave the way you want it to, you can always customize the objects being inserted to be hashed a particular way.

You can do this by adding two new methods to your existing class:

```
class Student
  def hash
    self.id
  end

  def eql?(student)
    self.id == student.id
  end
end
```

By defining `hash` to return a value based on `id`, Hash will consider these two candidates for the same spot in the hash. The second definition declares "hash equivalence" between any two objects that have the same hash value.

This will work well provided your `id` values fit into a conventional 32-bit Fixnum and aren't 64-bit BIGINT database values.

As fl00r points out, this will only work if your `id` is immutable. For most databases this tends to be the case. Changing `id` on the fly is probably a really bad idea, though, as it can lead to total chaos and mind-blowing bugs.

Comment: I blame my ill-chosen example. The hash is not meant to be a database table and does not need to key on a unique identifier. Another might key on `name` or `seat_number`, which can be constantly changing.

Comment: There are plenty of in-memory DB's available. I've used Apache Derby on a project for a similar purpose.

Answer (score 1):

This is a hard problem. Database vendors can make money because it is a hard problem. You are basically looking to implement traditional RDBMS *indices*: search through derived data, to provide fast lookup to the data it was derived from, while allowing that data to change. If you want to access the data from multiple threads, you'll quickly run into all the issues that make it hard to make a database ACID compliant.

I suggest putting the data into a database, adding the necessary indices and letting the database -- an application optimized for this exact purpose -- do the work.

Comment: Now that you've pointed it out seems like it is indeed more difficult than I would care to solve on my own. I'll probably stick to the bad O(n) solution. Using a DB is too slow for this in-memory app.